# Is there any way to avoid putting the datatype in LINQ query

Tags: vb.net, linq

i have a linq query like this i dont want to put the Datatype as in some case i don't know what the datatype returned from database

```
Dim orders As DataTable = ds3.Tables(0)
Dim query = From row In orders
            Group row By S_type = row.Field(Of Decimal)("S_type") Into MonthGroup = Group
            Select New With {
                Key S_type,
                .TotalLocal = MonthGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Double)("TotalLocal"))
            }
```

Comment: Could `(Of Object)` be what you're looking for?

Comment: i want to remove Of Decimal or Of Double from my code as i said in many cases i don't know the returned datatype

Comment: `(Of Object)` will accept all datatypes.

Comment: It works? Not with `Sum`!